# The binary operation $a\star b=\frac{a+b}{1+ab}$ on points in the interval $-1<x<1$

Tags: group-theory

I saw the following question in an abstract algebra book:

> Let $G=\{a\in \mathbb{R}\mid -1<a<1 \}$. Show that
>   $G$ is a group under the binary operation 
>   $$a\star b=\frac{a+b}{1+ab}$$
>   and show that the map $f(x)=\displaystyle \ln\frac{1+x}{1-x}$ is an isomorphism  from $G$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

Solving this is straightforward.

My question is:

> Where such binary operation comes from? Also, I realized $f$ is inverse of the function $\tanh(x/2)$. Are there any connections with other areas?

Comment: The operation comes precisely from the map $f$. In general, if you have a bijective map from a set to a group, you can use this to define a group structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the similarity of 
$$\tanh(x+y)=\frac {\tanh (x)+\tanh(y)}{1+\tanh(x)\tanh(y)}$$

with

$$       a\star b=\frac{a+b}{1+ab} $$

which may be used to prove the isomorphism of the two groups.

Comment: Use **\tanh** by the way, to generate the following: $\tanh$ ....... Oh, somebody else already did it :)